# JApplet in Jar file can only be run from html contained in Jar file

Tags: java, html, jar, applet, appletviewer

I have a JApplet that is based off an application. I need it to read in a text based file containing all of it's data. So I stuck it in the Jar file and everything became happy in AppletViewer.

Unfortunately not everything is happy in browser land.

When I try to run the applet in a browser from a html page which is not in the jar, then I get the good old: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission

(it then lists the location of the jar on my filesystem and the !resource address)

But if I open the jar file up in a zip extractor/viewer like winzip and open the page that launches the applet (that I put inside the jar) it works fine. As expected, it can only access resources that have the same host, which seems in this case to come right down to the jar file itself.

SO my question is WTF? Can I open the html file inside the jar file from a browser... even inside an iframe or anything would be ok, as long as it doesn't further mess up the permissions.

Or can I call the applet from a html page outside the jar? I'm not using JNLP right now, cos I wanted to cobble together a prototype applet ASAP.

```
<applet code = 'CatalogApplet' 
archive = 'ContactCatalog.jar', 
width = 1000, 
height = 800 />
```

Is the entirity of the HTML call to the applet.

I'm not going to sign it, because it really shouldn't need signed. I am just wanting to call back to jar.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. The HTML file tells the browser about the JAR file, not the other way around. Do you mean that you can't access some *other* resource inside the JAR file from your applet? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want a way to run the html from within the jar, from a browser, not from any java code at all. I don't know why but I can't seem to ever get an AppletContext that isn't null, so I have to resort to weird things to load text or images into applets. This just happens to be a very strange work around.

Comment: This is all meaningless. A browser can't see an HTML file inside a JAR. All it can do is execute an applet that's in a JAR. If there is 'no Java code at all', there is no applet so there is no AppletContext either. This doesn't make any sense yet.

Answer (score 1):

The file should be accessed via URL, not by FileInputStream. Use this to get the URL:

```
URL urlToText = this.getClass().getResource("path/to/the.html");
```

That will work in a sand-boxed applet.

Comment: Er, I didn't want a way to call the html from java code, I wanted a way to call the html inside the jar from a browser.

Comment: I still find your explanation to be about as clear as mud.  Perhaps if you explained *why* you are trying to do what you're trying to do, it will make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

the clean way is :
package your ".class" files in a jar . have an html file outside the jar that references your jar inside applet tag. if your applet requires access to user filesystem then the right way to go is to sign your applet jar. see http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html

Comment: They are packaged in a jar, but unfortunately if I have a html file outside the jar, then the code can no longer load resources inside the jar. (Even thou the code is in the jar.)